# Generate graphs and diagrams with Doxygen

Tags: ubuntu, doxygen

I need to generate class diagrams or a graph of a C++ project using Doxygen, I installed it on Ubntu 12.04 as follow:

```
 sudo apt-get install doxygen
 sudo apt-get install doxygen-gui
```

now I don't know how to run the gui, or how to generate the graphs from the surce code, the manual doesn't help.

Answer (score 12):

you need to install graphviz for diagrams

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz
sudo apt-get install doxygen-gui
```

than to start doxygen gui type in terminal type

```
doxywizard
```